# Python - tracing module execution

Tags: python, module

I am running a large `script.py` with many `modules` being `imported`, like:

```
from module import *
```

when I run it, I am printing some undesired result `[u'Brewer and Shipley']`, *at importing time*, which I'm not being able to trace back to its `method` and stop it from being executed.

Is there something I can use to trace and stop this?

Comment: Doesn't help in the short-term, but in the future don't do this: `from module import *`. It's always a bad idea, except perhaps in throwaway code. To debug in the short-term, write a new script just with the imports: run, comment out import line, run again. Repeat until you find the culprit.

Comment: @FMc, thanks, noted.

Comment: You can also add this code to the top of your script: `import sys; sys.stdout = None`. When the imported code tries to print, it will blow up with a stacktrace that you can check.

Comment: great. you should answer it, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While blowing to find out who blew is excellent suggestion by @FMc,
Here is another trick I use

`import X
print 'X imported'
import Y
print 'Y imported'
import Z
print 'Z imported'`

This will also help you narrow down module with a problem. :)

You can optimize this by doing binary search by printing middle points, but I guess that's over-engg.